# Getting the following error, "ImportError: cannot import name 'rnn_cell_impl' " on tensorfow V 1.4.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/layers/recurrent.py in <module>()
     12     # Fix for TF 1.1.0 and under
     13     from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops.core_rnn import static_rnn as _rnn, static_bidirectional_rnn as _brnn
---> 14     from tensorflow.python.ops.rnn import rnn_cell_impl as _rnn_cell, dynamic_rnn as _drnn
     15     from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops import core_rnn_cell
     16 

ImportError: cannot import name 'rnn_cell_impl'
```

Getting the following error. TF version 1.4 .

Answer (score 0):

Post your code also. Try following way,

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn_cell_impl
```

Comment: import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

# things we need for Tensorflow
import numpy as np
import tflearn
import tensorflow as tf
import random
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn_cell_impl
# from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops.rnn_cell import _Linear
#import tensorflow.python.ops.tensor_array_ops

Comment: For the above code i added your line of code but it still does not work.

Comment: I think the way you are importing (as I see in your code) is not correct. Do "from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn_cell_impl" then reference any entity inside "rnn_cell_impl" module using rnn_cell_impl.entity_name like rnn_cell_impl._rnn_cell

Comment: Got it , works like a charm. Thank you so much for your time and effort.